# How I can Solve This Error In Telerik RadScheduler In Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net

I have an error in the binding Of The Telerik RadScheduler I need help. The error is

```
DataBinding: 'Calender.Model.RadSchedulerData' does not contain a property with the name 'ID'.
```

I want to know what is the problem? I make alot of search but I do not get the right answer. Please any one know this error please tell me, Thanks.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        List<RadSchedulerData> lstrsd = new List<RadSchedulerData>();
        NewCalenderDBEntities1 Context = new NewCalenderDBEntities1();
        int UserID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["UserID"]); 
        //int UserID = 1;
        Session["UserID"] = UserID;
        var Data = (from r in Context.Users 
                   where r.ID == UserID
                    select new { AppointmentTbl = r.Appointments }).ToList();

        var D = (from r in Context.Appointments
                 where r.RoleId == 1
                    select new RadSchedulerData { Subject = r.Subject, StartDate = r.Start, EndDate = r.End }).ToList();
        lstrsd.AddRange(D);
        foreach (var item in Data)
        {
            foreach (var i in item.AppointmentTbl)
            {

                    var DD = Context.Appointments.Where(w => w.RoleId == 2 && w.ID == i.ID).Select(s => new RadSchedulerData
                    {
                        Subject = s.Subject,
                        StartDate = s.Start,
                        EndDate = s.End
                    }).ToList();
                    lstrsd.AddRange(DD);

                    var AllSharedData = Context.Appointments.Where(w => w.RoleId == 3 && w.ID == i.ID).Select(s => new RadSchedulerData
                    {
                        Subject = s.Subject,
                        StartDate = s.Start,
                        EndDate = s.End
                    }).ToList();
                    lstrsd.AddRange(AllSharedData);



            }
        }  



        RadScheduler1.EnableCustomAttributeEditing = true;
        RadScheduler1.DataKeyField = "ID";
        RadScheduler1.DataSource = lstrsd;
        RadScheduler1.DataBind();


    }
```

Comment: Please Any One Know The Answer Please Reply Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error message carefully again, you will probably see the problem by yourself:

> DataBinding: 'Calender.Model.RadSchedulerData' does not contain a property with the name 'ID'.

It simply means that the control is trying to fetch a value for the property `ID` on the `RadSchedulerData` class and it cannot find it. This could mean, it doesn't exist or that it is not public.

The reason the control is trying to read that specific property on that class is because in the code sample, the `DataSource` property of the `RadScheduler` is set to a `List<RadSchedulerData>` and its `DataKeyField` property to `ID`.

To fix the binding error, you either

1. create (and populate) an `ID` property in the `RadSchedulerData` class
2. make the `ID` property public in the `RadSchedulerData` class
3. give the `RadScheduler.DataKeyField` a different property name that exists in `RadSchedulerData`
4. change the `RadScheduler.DataSource` property to a list of other object types that have an `ID` property .